# How to embed yammer private messages on my website?

Tags: javascript, embed, yammer

I know how to embed a feed which has a certain ID. I already did it. Now I'd like to implement the following functionality: If a user receives a private message, it will appear on an embedded feed. The best option in my opinion would be to embed the whole "chat window", but I didn't find a single code sample on the web. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Yammer API](https://developer.yammer.com/)? Here's a particular page on requesting [private messages](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/messagesprivatejson).

Comment: Well I did, but their documentation doesn't explain exactly how to use it. They didn't provide any code snippet or a working example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot really embed private messages like you can with feeds, because Yammer's REST APIs (incl. private messages) require authentication via OAuth 2.0. That means you have to create a Yammer API application which will ask your users to log in and allow you to access their messages. The overall concept of that described in their documentation [here](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/faq#section-which-api-should-i-use-) and [here](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/oauth-2).

Yammer provides several SDKs you can use, one of them is the Javascript SDK. I pieced togehter a simple example of how you can ask users to log in and then it will display their private messages. Mind you, this is a very simple solution, I just tested it on a single one-to-one conversation.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-app-id="YOUR-APP-CLIENT-ID" src="https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_js_sdk.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="yammer-login"></span>
<div id="messages"></div>
<script>
yam.connect.loginButton('#yammer-login', function (resp) {
    if (resp.authResponse) {
      document.getElementById('yammer-login').innerHTML = 'Welcome to Yammer!';
    }
});

var msgdiv = document.querySelector("#messages");

yam.getLoginStatus(
  function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
      console.log("logged in");
      var myId = response.authResponse.user_id;
      yam.platform.request({
        url: "messages/private.json",
        method: "GET",
        success: function (response) {
            console.log("The request was successful.");
            var usernames = {};
            response.references.forEach(function(ref){
                if(ref.type === "user") {
                    usernames[ref.id] = ref.full_name;
                }
            });
            response.messages.forEach(function(message){
                var msg = document.createElement("span");
                msg.innerHTML = usernames[message.sender_id] + ": " + message.body.parsed + "<br/>";
                msgdiv.appendChild(msg);
            })
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log("There was an error with the request.");
            console.dir(private);
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      console.log("not logged in")
    }
  }
);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The response from the `messages/private.json` API endpoint is a JSON file that you can go through. It includes information about the message and the users involved in the conversation.